# trying to run npm start on a discord bot but i keep getting a 'node:events' error. While using node v16.13.1

Tags: javascript

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "5ambot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

when i run npm start i gett an error in **internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892**

**error**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- DIR\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js
- DIR\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- DIR\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (DIR\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'DIR\\node_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\BaseClient.js',
    'DIR\\node_modules\\discord.js\\src\\index.js',
    'DIR\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

i tried reinstalling package-lock:
-rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm start

didn't work. I am out of ideas and everyone says its cuz the node version is too low and i saw no other solution. Please help

edit: i came to a conclusion that its the discord.js that isn't loading correctly with npm install discord.js

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of `index.js` too?

Answer (score 0):

try

Delete node_modules
run

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm run start
```

or try yarn

```
yarn
```

Comment: tried it but it didn't work

Comment: From the error details, it seems discord.js package is not installed. try installing globally ussing npm install -g discord.js then rerun npm install @GalPodlipnik

Comment: yea still nothing...same error! @Prateek